# In a TabbedPage, how can I push another Page over the current subpage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

(Complete code example is available here:
https://github.com/csvan/TabbedPageModalDemo)

I have the following page structure in my Xamarin.Forms app:

```
namespace TabbedPageModalDemo
{
    public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MyTabbedPage ()
        {
            Title = "Tabbed Page";

            Children.Add (new MyTabPage ());
        }
    }
}

namespace TabbedPageModalDemo
{
    public class MyTabPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyTabPage ()
        {
            Title = "Tab Page";

            var button = new Button {
                Text = "Open Modal"
            };

            // Using PushModal as an example - PushAsync also fills the whole screen.
            button.Clicked += (sender, e) => Navigation.PushModalAsync (new MyModalPage ());

            var stack = new StackLayout ();
            stack.Children.Add (button);

            Content = stack;
        }
    }
}

namespace TabbedPageModalDemo
{
    public class MyModalPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyModalPage ()
        {
            Title = "Modal Page";

            var label = new Label {
                Text = "I am a modal page!"
            };

            var stack = new StackLayout ();
            stack.Children.Add (label);

            Content = stack;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is the following: when I press the button, I would like MyModalPage to *only take up the same space that is occupied by MyTabPage*. Currently, it fills the entire screen, covering MyTabbedPage as well. *Note that the same happens if I use PushAsync instead*.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try used padding inside your current modal page?

```
Padding = new Thickness(0,30,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be to use NavigationPages instead of a ContentPage as your Child-Elements. A good example can be seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/).